# Operator identity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $T:\mathcal{D}(A)\to\mathcal{H}$ be a unbounded, self-adjoint, operator with positive spectrum $\sigma(T)\subset [\varepsilon,\infty)$ for $\varepsilon>0$. Hence $T$ is bijective with bounded inverse. Now, consider the functions
$$f:\lambda\mapsto e^{-\delta\lambda}$$
$$g:\lambda\mapsto e^{-\delta\frac{1}{\lambda}}\quad \text{ for } \quad\lambda\neq 0\quad \text{ and } \quad 0\quad \text{ otherwise }$$
for $\delta>0$.

> How to show that $f(T)=g(T^{-1})$ where both operators are defined using the spectral theorem, $f(T)$ using the spectral calculus of the unbounded operator $T$ and $g(T^{-1})$ the spectral calculus of the bounded operator $T^{-1}$?

Both $f$ and $g$ are continuous and bounded on the relevant spectra $\sigma(T)\subset [\varepsilon,\infty)$ and $\sigma(T^{-1})\subset [0,1/\varepsilon)$. In particular, $f(T)$ and $g(T^{-1})$ are both bounded operators, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: If $T$ is a multiplication operator, $T = M_\phi$, then $f(T) = M_{f\circ \phi}$ and $g(T^{-1}) = g(M_{1/\phi}) = M_{g\circ(1/\phi)} = M_{f\circ \phi}$. By the multiplication operator form of the spectral theorem, that's enough.